# Spring security configuration with roles and permission

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring-Security in my project.

I have users like Admin(ROLE_ADMIN), Manager(ROLE_MANAGER), User(ROLE_USER). Each has Roles and Permissions.

Admin has all permissions, manager has Add, Edit, and View and user has Add and View.

I want to configured authorization based on permission not by roles.

**Page A**: Only admin and manager can access and they need Add, View, Edit permission.

**Page B**: All users can access this page but they need Add, View.

Here the User can easily access Page A because they have "add" and "view" permission.

I did following things in my provider implementation.

1. Get user role.
2. Get Permissions based on role.
3. Put All the permissions in the list of GrantedAuthority.

Should I put all permission with the role in the GrantedAuthority list?

Could you please give me a suggestion for configuration part.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?
This is interesting to me.